# Automated way to get binary variables from a database

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression

I have a problem in relation to a database related to dengue. I have in this database some variables, among them the variable "Cases", which indicates the number of dengue cases in a given period. But I want to apply the logistic regression model to these data, so the idea is to make this variable with integers, to become a binary variable, that is, for places that did not have dengue cases in that period, I want to put 0 in place of the quantity that I already have, and for places that have had cases, put 1. As there are 35628 lines, I want to do it in an automated way, to avoid doing it, manually. Would anyone have any idea how to proceed in order to put this idea into practice? I'm new to programming and I'm trying to implement it in the R language. If they know of a package that does this, it helps a lot. Each neighborhood is conditioned to a number.

I appreciate any help and thank you very much.

| neighborhood | Dates | Cases | precipitation | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jan/14 | 10 | 149,6 | 33,25 |
| 1 | Fev/14 | 0 | 254 | 30,1 |
| 2 | Mar/14 | 6 | 150 | 25,4 |
| 3 | Apr/14 | 0 | 244,1 | 32,5 |
| 4 | May/14 | 3 | 44,3 | 33,2 |

I appreciate any help and thank you very much.

Comment: you could use a use try catch to convert every value on a single row, tag the columns for conversion to number if successful, and convert all values in tagged columns.

Comment: (R) `dat$CasesBinary <- +(dat$Cases > 0)`? This is still integer, but it's only `0`/`1`, and most logistic regression tools in R that I've worked with will use this just fine. You can also use just `<- dat$Cases > 0` which will return `logical` (`TRUE` or `FALSE`), which should also work just fine.

Comment: @BlackRaven, in your (currently deleted) answer, I think you need to replace `if x=0` with `if x==0`.

Comment: @BlackRaven Would you have any documentation with examples of this that you mentioned? I appreciate your help, again. I need to understand how I'm going to start writing the code until the database looks the way I want to finally apply the glm function.

Comment: Hi @wgrt, I've used 2 concepts "lambda" and "list comprehension", see https://dev.to/suvhotta/python-lambda-and-list-comprehension-5128 or you can google them separately

Comment: Hi @r2evans, thanks for the good catch! I've edited it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### R

Pick from among

```r
dat$CasesBin1 <- (dat$Cases > 0)
dat$CasesBin2 <- +(dat$Cases > 0)
dat
#   neighborhood  Dates Cases precipitation Temperature CasesBin1 CasesBin2
# 1            0 Jan/14    10         149.6       33.25      TRUE         1
# 2            1 Fev/14     0         254.0       30.10     FALSE         0
# 3            2 Mar/14     6         150.0       25.40      TRUE         1
# 4            3 Apr/14     0         244.1       32.50     FALSE         0
# 5            4 May/14     3          44.3       33.20      TRUE         1
```

In R at least, most logistic regression tools I've used work fine with either `integer` (0/1) or `logical`, but you may need to verify with the tools you will use.

Data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(neighborhood = 0:4, Dates = c("Jan/14", "Fev/14", "Mar/14", "Apr/14", "May/14"), Cases = c(10L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 3L), precipitation = c(149.6, 254, 150, 244.1, 44.3), Temperature = c(33.25, 30.1, 25.4, 32.5, 33.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

### python

```py
In [13]: dat
Out[13]: 
   neighborhood   Dates  Cases  precipitation  Temperature
0             0  Jan/14     10          149.6        33.25
1             1  Fev/14      0          254.0        30.10
2             2  Mar/14      6          150.0        25.40
3             3  Apr/14      0          244.1        32.50
4             4  May/14      3           44.3        33.20

In [17]: dat['CasesBin1'] = dat['Cases'].apply(lambda x: (x > 0))
In [18]: dat['CasesBin2'] = dat['Cases'].apply(lambda x: int(x > 0))
In [19]: dat
Out[19]: 
   neighborhood   Dates  Cases  ...  Temperature  CasesBin1  CasesBin2
0             0  Jan/14     10  ...        33.25       True          1
1             1  Fev/14      0  ...        30.10      False          0
2             2  Mar/14      6  ...        25.40       True          1
3             3  Apr/14      0  ...        32.50      False          0
4             4  May/14      3  ...        33.20       True          1

[5 rows x 7 columns]
```

Data:

```py
In [11]: js
Out[11]: '[{"neighborhood":0,"Dates":"Jan/14","Cases":10,"precipitation":149.6,"Temperature":33.25},{"neighborhood":1,"Dates":"Fev/14","Cases":0,"precipitation":254,"Temperature":30.1},{"neighborhood":2,"Dates":"Mar/14","Cases":6,"precipitation":150,"Temperature":25.4},{"neighborhood":3,"Dates":"Apr/14","Cases":0,"precipitation":244.1,"Temperature":32.5},{"neighborhood":4,"Dates":"May/14","Cases":3,"precipitation":44.3,"Temperature":33.2}]'
In [12]: dat = pd.read_json(js)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't see you would like to implement it in the R Language. Below is suggested code in Python...

Assuming that the table is in a DataFrame `df`, you could create a new column 'dengue_cases' with 0 when there are no cases, and 1 when there are cases

```
df['Cases'] = df['Cases'].astype('int')   #to ensure the correct data type in column
df['dengue_cases'] = df['Cases'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x==0 else 1)
```

The above lines will create a new column. If you are replacing the original column use below line:

```
df['Cases'] = df['Cases'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x==0 else 1)
```